# Construct a 3x3 matrix given eigenvalues, but no eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to construct a 3x3 matrix with eigenvalues of 20, -3, and 0. However, we are not given eigenvectors and it can not be upper triangular. I know there are infinite number of matrices but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What about $V D V^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

Choose some invertible $3\times3$ matrix $M$ such that$$N=M\begin{bmatrix}20&0&0\\0&-3&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}M^{-1}$$is *not* upper triangular. Then $N$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

every three by three orthogonal matrix with positive determinant (therefore $+1$) can be written, with real $a,b,c,d$ not all zero, as

$$
P =
\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2&2(-ad+bc)&2(ac+bd)\\
2(ad+bc)&a^2 - b^2+c^2- d^2&2(-ab+cd)\\
2(-ac+bd)&2(ab+cd)&a^2 - b^2 - c^2 + d^2\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Starting with your diagonal matrix $D,$ you can get a symmetric matrix that is probably not diagonal with
$$  P^T D P  $$

The first example with $a,b,c,d$ integers and absolute values of the nine elements all distinct has $a=1,b=6,c=2,d=4:$

$$
P =
\frac{1}{57}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
17&16&52\\
32&-47&4\\
44&28&-23\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We get one example,

$$
P^T DP =
\frac{1}{3249}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2708&9952&17296\\
9952&-1507&17204\\
17296&17204&54032\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$